# How do i open an .exp file?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a .exp file that I need to open in a database. I have tried to google for answers on how to open the file to view the tables, but to no avail.

Could someone help me with a step-by-step guide on how to open/import the file to view the data?

Comment: [.exp](https://fileinfo.com/extension/exp) is used as the extension for a bunch of file formats... which one do you have?

Comment: Hello, its a database file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imp` assuming that's an Oracle file:

`imp system/data file=c:\tmp\dbbackup.exp show=y`

Discussed here on Oracle:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/567680